# Using .ico for toolbar button of Firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, icons, xul, toolbar

I want to use an .ico file which contains my addon icon with different sizes (say, 16-24-32 px) as a toolbar button icon. When I'm setting it as an icon for both toolbar sizes and for addon details page, 16px version is always chosen.

Is it possible to make FF pick the right size automatically? So that if toolbar icon size is "large", it'll pick 24px version instead of stretching 16px.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS:

```
{
    -moz-image-region: rect(0 24px 24px 0);
     list-style-image: url("chrome://sidebar/skin/icon_24x24.png");
}

toolbar[iconsize="small"]
{
    -moz-image-region: rect(0 16px 16px 0);
     list-style-image: url("chrome://sidebar/skin/icon_16x16.png");
}
```

Comment: I know how to do it using separate PNG icons. I wanted to know if it's possible to give FF just an .ico file with all needed sizes and make it choose the one it needs according to container size.

Comment: No, Firefox does not grab image sizes out of ICO files.